# junit5 - run tests in parallel (without forkCount in pom)

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5

To execute my JUnit tests in parallel I have used the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10174630/3842201) (Thanks to [@peanut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596532/peanut) & [@Reid Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/888059/reid-mac) ). This works well for JUnit 4 but I'm trying to migrate from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5. Since JUnit 5 tests are executed by `JUnitPlatform`, which extends directly `Runner`, the equivalent is not possible with JUnit 5. Does JUnit 5 have any method like `setScheduler`? Below are my code snippets.

*JUnit4Runner.class*

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;
import org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder;
import org.junit.runners.model.RunnerScheduler;

public final class JUnit4Runner extends Suite {


    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
    public @interface Concurrent {
        int threads() default 1;
    }

    /**
     * Used by JUnit Concurrent
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674774/running-junit-test-in-parallel-on-suite-level
     */
    public AJUnit4Runner2(Class<?> suiteClass, RunnerBuilder builder) throws InitializationError {
        super(suiteClass, builder);
        setScheduler(new RunnerScheduler() {
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
                    suiteClass.isAnnotationPresent(Concurrent.class)
                            ? suiteClass.getAnnotation(Concurrent.class).threads()
                            : 1,
                    new NamedThreadFactory(suiteClass.getSimpleName()));
            CompletionService<Void> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Void>(executorService);
            Queue<Future<Void>> tasks = new LinkedList<Future<Void>>();

            @Override
            public void schedule(Runnable childStatement) {
                tasks.offer(completionService.submit(childStatement, null));
            }

            @Override
            public void finished() {
                try {
                    while (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
                        tasks.remove(completionService.take());
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } finally {
                    while (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
                        tasks.poll().cancel(true);
                    }
                    executorService.shutdownNow();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class NamedThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

        final AtomicInteger poolNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
        final AtomicInteger threadNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
        final ThreadGroup group;

        public NamedThreadFactory(String poolName) {
            group = new ThreadGroup(poolName + "-" + poolNumber.getAndIncrement());
        }

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            return new Thread(group, r, group.getName() + "-thread-" + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(), 0);
        }
    }

}
```

JUnit5 runner class looks something like this

*JUnit5Runner.class*

```
public class JUnit5Runner extends JUnitPlatform {
    public JUnit5Runner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        super.run(notifier);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Junit 5.3 M1 now does support parallel test execution. 
As it mentioned in the [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution), it is currently an experimental feature. You can enable it by setting the `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled` configuration parameter to true in junit-platform.properties.